# How can I shred all disks but /dev/sda and log the output to a file?

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, secure-erase, shredding

I'm trying to make one command that will take all drives that are not sda and run shred on them and dump the output to a log file. So far I have

```
find /dev/ -name "sd?" -not -name "sda" -exec [shred -fvz {} > /home/ben/ProjectsInProgress/ShredLogs/$(hdparm -I {} | grep 'Serial\ Number' |cut -f2- -d:).log 2>&1 &] \;
```

As you can see, I have gotten a fair distance into this with searching google, but now i ran into something I don't know what to do because the output I got is

```
[1] 13097
{}: No such file or directory
]: command not found
[1]+  Exit 1                  find /dev/ -name "sd?" -not -name "sda" -exec [shred -fvz {} > /home/ben/ProjectsInProgress/ShredLogs/$(hdparm -I {} | grep 'Serial\ Number' |cut -f2- -d:).log 2>&1
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Also, I am currently working on this problem but suggestions would be nice. When I run

```
shred -fvz /dev/sdb > /home/ben/ProjectsInProgress/ShredLogs/$(hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep 'Serial\ Number' |cut -f2- -d:).log 2>&1
```

I get an ambiguous redirect error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Though the original answer tells you part of why your `find` command didn't work, the loop using `find` won't work for USB HDDs. Scroll to the bottom of the answer for a better version.

Note that the logging won't work at all with USB flash drives; `hdparm` is only for HDDs.

---

Your `find` command won't work. At all. Why?

There are a few problems, but the major one is this: The `-exec` option looks in the `PATH` for an executable with the name of its first argument and executes it with any other arguments to `find` up to a semicolon. **It does *not* pass its arguments to a shell, which means using** `$(...)`**, redirection, etc will not work.**

How do you fix this? There are a few ways.

The most obvious might be to pass your command to a shell:

```
find . -name testing12345 -exec bash -c '...$(...)... > /path/to/some/file 2>&1' \;
```

Yes, this works, but in a complicated expression with multiple types of quotes, escaping can quickly become a nightmare.

Often, using a loop is the easiest way to do this. Since you already have a working `find` command, the easiest way to do this is to take the `-exec` arguments off of it and pipe it into a loop:

```
find (your find arguments here) -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do
    # process "$filename"
done
```

`IFS=` and the `-print0` and `-d $'\0'` options to `find` and `read` avoid problems with newlines in file names. The `-r` option ensures that `read` doesn't process backslashes in the file names.

Combining that and fixes to your other problems, we get this, which seems to work:

```
find /dev/ -name "sd?" -not -name "sda" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do
    if (hdparm -i "$filename" > /dev/null 2>&1); then
        shred -fvz "$filename" > /home/ben/ProjectsInProgress/ShredLogs/$(hdparm -i "$filename" | grep -o 'SerialNo=\S*' |cut -f2 -d=).log 2>&1 &
    fi
done
```

I've only tested it myself with an `echo` statement in place of `shred` since I don't want to shred my disks, so please tell me if it works.

---

EDIT: The `find` version is broken for USB HDDs. This modified version that uses `lsblk` works correctly:

```
lsblk -ld | grep -o '^sd[b-z]' | while read -r filename; do
    filename="/dev/$filename"
    shred -fvz "$filename" > "/home/ben/ProjectsInProgress/ShredLogs/$(hdparm -I "$filename" | grep -o 'Serial Number:\s*\S*' | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/^\s*//').log" 2>&1 &
done
```

Comment: @BenStumpf What error did it give (or did it give no error but do nothing)? `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename` reads in the filenames piped to the loop from `find`, seperating them by null bytes (the `-print0` option tells `find` to seperate the files it outputs by null bytes) and processes them one by one.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. The script did nothing. if i remove the if statement i get the ambiguous redirect error

Comment: @BenStumpf It didn't even create a log file? That's odd. You ran it in a root shell, right?

Comment: yes i ran it as root and no it did not make the log files

Comment: The script now does nothing

Comment: @BenStumpf The new version also does nothing? Odd. I added another debug statement; please post its output

Comment: Processing /dev/sdc
Ignoring /dev/sdc

Answer (score 2):

This script should do what you want. Note that it must run as root!

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
logpath="/home/ben/ProjectsInProgress/ShredLogs"
lsblk -l | grep -o '^sd[b-z] ' | while read f; do
    logfile="$logpath/$(hdparm -i "/dev/$f" | grep -oP "(?<=SerialNo=)\w+")"
    shred -fvz "$f" &> "$logfile"
done
```

<sub>Thanks to @[terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) for providing this improved (and hopefully now fixed) version.</sub>

Please tell me whether it works, I'm not really motivated to test shredding my own disks...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45469/discussion-on-answer-by-byte-commander-how-can-i-shred-all-disks-but-dev-sda-an).